# Uber API Payment method & Ride Estimate 500 internal server error

Tags: macos, uber-api

we have been working with the Uber API, after our scopes got approved and we are testing it for production we are getting 500 errors on payment & ride estimate.

URL We are using for request is

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/payment-methods",baseURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request addValue:@"en_US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", delegate->AccessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[self performNetworkOperationWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *requestDictionary, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


    if(!error)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }}];
```

where  baseURL = @"https://api.uber.com/v1.2";
And delegate->AccessToken= AccessToken we get at the time of Auth2.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6080006374c0> { URL: https://api.uber.com/v1.2/payment-methods } { status code: 500, headers {
   Connection = "keep-alive";
   "Content-Length" = 75;
   "Content-Type" = "application/json";
   Date = "Mon, 02 Jan 2017 07:44:43 GMT";
   Server = nginx;
   "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=604800";
   "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
   "X-Uber-App" = "uberex-nonsandbox, migrator-uberex-optimus";
   "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
```

Comment: Can you share the example request / response? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: I have added my complete request above. I am trying to get 200 success response for payment_methods,and I am using " api.uber.com/v1.2/payment-methods" URL for the same. We get proper response for the development mode account but once our scopes got approved we got a 500 error.

Comment: Can you try again as I think the issue is now resolved.

Comment: Yes,fortunately its resolved now.We are getting all the responses properly. thank you.